# Reading from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am very new to Firebase and JS itself as well, and it is not the easiest thing to understand.

So, I have a Firebase real time databse set up with dummy "users" profiles, that each contain different properties.
[image: picture of database entry, example]

i am trying to call user's properties.
I have managed to achieved it with the following approach:

```
let installDateRef = database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/installationDate`);
let lastUsedDateRef = database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/lastUsed`);
 installDateRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        installationDate.innerText = (snapshot.val());
    }, function (error) {
        installationDate.innerText = `Error: ${error.code}`
    });

    lastUsedDateRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        lastUsedDate.innerText = (snapshot.val());
    }, function (error) {
        lastUsedDate.innerText = `Error: ${error.code}`
    });
```

But in my application I want to display all of the user information, so copying this ".on" function seems like overkill.
Someone said that there is cleaner approach like this below

```
const firebasePromises = [
database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/installationDate`),
database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/lastUsed`)
];
Promise.all(firebasePromises).then(([_installationDate, _lastUsed]) => {
installationDate.innerText = (_installationDate.val());
lastUsedDate.innerText = (_lastUsed.val());
})
```

But I honest to God cannot make it work. It either returns undefined or returns array of my promises const.
.val() does not work at all even, saying that this is not a function.

Any help would on the best and working practice would be soooo much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your `firebasePromises` does not actually contain any promises.  Those are just DocumentReference objects.  You have to call `once()` to get a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Doug Stevenson thank you! This is exactly what was needed:

```
const firebasePromises = [
        database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/installationDate`).once('value'),
        database.ref(`users/${userAccount}/lastUsed`).once('value'),
        ];

        Promise.all(firebasePromises).then(snap => {
            installationDateHTML.innerText = snap[0].val();
            lastUsedDateHTML.innerText     = snap[1].val();

        })
```